# How do you rotate a quaternion a specified angle around the y axis?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, quaternions

I'm not quite sure if my question has been asked before in general terms. Whenever it has been asked, it is in terms of a specific language.

Let's say I have an objects rotation represented as a quaternion **q = {w, x, y, z}**.

I want to rotate this quaternion **A** radians around the y axis.

Since quaternions are already a measure of rotation, should I just add (or multiply) another quaternion representing the desired rotation to q? How would one go about this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, multiply a y-rotation quaternion to the left side of q. See quaternion laws for details.

Comment: Refer my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779300/rotating-a-vector-around-an-axis-with-quaternion/29804041#29804041

Answer (score 2):

You are right

> Since quaternions are already a measure of rotation, should I just add (or multiply) another quaternion representing the desired rotation to q?

You should multiply current rotation quaternion with desired rotation quaternion.  Depending on, local frame "Y" or global frame "Y" you should multiply from left to right or right to left.